# how do you sum the last element in a spreadsheet row using tuples and openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I need to sum all of the cellObj.values in the final cell of each row listed below. The last element of each row is a float. Ideas or suggestions?

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('DIGITAL.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('DIGITAL')

for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['B2':'O828']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        print(cellObj.coordinate, cellObj.value)
    print('--- END OF ROW ---')
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough. Convert each row to a tuple, use [-1] to get the last cell and use the builtin `sum` to do the calculation.